# названия классов в пакетах (чистый код)

Tags: java, чистый-код

Пытаюсь дать классам названия в соответствии с "чистым кодом". Я так понимаю, что чем короче и понятнее название, тем лучше.

В моем проекте множество пакетов, и в пакетах подчас находятся классы, унаследованные от классов из других пакетов. Надо ли давать этим классам разные имена, которые будут содержать не просто имя, а еще и некоторое описание объекта? Или все же чем короче, тем лучше, а средства среды разработки обеспечат понимание откуда этот класс?

Например есть класс File из пакета dataObject. Этот класс наследуется классом File из пакета buffer.
Надо ли в пакете buffer назвать класс BufferFile, а класс в пакете dataObject назвать dataFile?

Иными словами какая структура лучше:

1)

- dataObject
  -File
- buffer
  -File

2. 

- dataObject
  -DataFile
- buffer
  -BufferFile

Comment: Как хотите,так и называйте. Главное что бы вам было понятно. А все рекомендации в основном для тех, кому код нужно будет передавать другим

Comment: @ArtyMorris сам разработчик через полгода-год и есть этот "другой". Так что все рекомендации применимы и в случае с одним разработчиком тоже. А так-то да, вопрос дискуссионный. Я бы сказал, назовите, как кажется правильным сейчас. Главное, когда становится неудобно - переименовать. Для этого хорошо иметь тесты, чтобы проверить, что рефакторинг не сломал ничего. Вот эта возможность относительно легко менять без страха важнее, чем конкретный вид кода в данный момент.

Comment: Отчасти согласен, но всё равно надо что бы было понятно. Даже с бодуна

Comment: `Я так понимаю, что чем короче и понятнее название, тем лучше.` - длина названия класса не является критерием. Скажем так, чем понятнй - тем лушче + желательно быть кратким, но нельзя жертвовать понятностью ради краткости.

Comment: имена data классов показывают, чем этот класс является. Имена service классов - что они делают. Например, класс Person является персоной, а класс FileWriter пишет в файл.

Comment: также имейте ввиду, что правила по именованию классов работают при условии, что вы собдюдаете и остальные рекомендации. Если же у вас есть, например, класс, который не должен вообще существовать, то вы можете испытать проблемы с его именованием или начнете плодить классы типа XXXManager

Comment: Говоря о вашем вопросе file vs data file vs buffer file - классы, которые чем то являются, должны быть названы по этому принципу, а не по принципу как вы этот класс собрались ипользовать. Например, вы можете иметь класс File и испольщовать его как data object, чтобы хранить его в памяти или на жестком диске - зачем для каждого использования создавать свои версии классов мне не ведомо.